# RegExp for Unicode 13 Emojis

Tags: flutter, dart

I have found one example but it's for Unicode 11, anyone have one that works for Unicode 13?

```
/// A tweak regexp to pass all Emoji Unicode 11.0
/// TODO: improve this version, since it does not match the graphical bytes.

  static final RegExp REGEX_EMOJI = RegExp(r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this github I think this has what you are looking for I will like below.
[emoji-regex](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex)

Comment: I tried that but I get a ```Use valid regular expression syntax.dart(valid_regexps)``` error.

Comment: sorry look promising

Comment: thanks for trying the unicode website is down so its kinda hard to find.